# Add a desktop icon in OpenBox

Tags: openbox

I installed OpenBox and Google Chrome using following command:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xorg openbox google-chrome
```

When I start openbox, an empty black desktop is displayed.

I want to add a google-chrome icon to OpenBox desktop. How can I add an icon to OpenBox desktop?

Comment: Has been a while since I've been a full-time openbox user, but I've polished my answer, everything tests out on my Ubuntu 16.04, so let me know if you have any other questions. Cheers !

Comment: A pure Openbox session doesn't use a desktop, AFAIK. The "black desktop" is probably the root window. So what is your starting point? Why did you need to install `xorg`? Are you actually running some sort of distro with Openbox as the window manager such as Lubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start `nautilus -n` process. Desktop icons are managed by file manager, openbox provides only windows.  If you want to spawn that command on startup, follow instructions as explained in [openbox documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart).

You'll need to have `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file.
Basically you can run:

```
$ printf "nautilus -n &\n" >> .config/openbox/autostart
```

After that you can just copy `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to your desktop folder, log out and log back in - and you're done.

Comment: hum, tried this on debian buster and it seemed like nautilus was incapable of running without a root with (-n) anymore

Comment: @ThorSummoner Thanks for letting me know. Nautilus developers may have made some changes.